# Organizing a site like this according to geographic region

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

For the upcoming StackExchange offering. Let's say that you wanted to make one for each of the 50 State's tax laws.  What do you think would be the best way to organize that? Would you have to have 50 different versions, one for each state? Each state has differing and changing laws that are complex enough to certainly have the content.  And people with questions would use it big time during tax season. Would you have to pay for 50 different versions or could you put it all under the same domain?

Answer (score 2):

I think tags take care of this.  Create a tag per state, and you automatically have an area for tax questions for that state.  Plus, if a tax question relates to federal tax, a state-specific tax question could be tagged as federal, for example.

Comment: but wouldn't the initial page that users see be just a huge jumble of all 50 states mixed together?

Comment: Get some customization so that a user signs up by state, and then filter out the tags that are not from that state.
Also, just have every user auto-tag their question with their own state.

Comment: @devinb You're making a very huge assumption that such will be possible, and I can almost guarantee that it won't be

Comment: @Barack The functionality I've described would not be incredibly difficult to implement, because uses functionality that already exists. It would be a cheap and simply way to create localization and would allow them to seek new business avenues.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible, it just probably won't be available. Such is the problem with closed source software; there's never enough time to do everything you want. After working with various open source frameworks I would never pay for something closed source, there simply isn't enough room for the customizations I desire.